# Rest POST API working with POSTMAN but not working Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, rest, api, post, xamarin.forms

Heres the code to my HttpPost request

```
async void ContinueBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!CheckValidation())
    {
        LoginBLL cust = new LoginBLL();
        EncryptPassword encrypt = new EncryptPassword();

        cust.name = txtFieldName.Text;
        cust.email = txtFieldEmail.Text;
        cust.Password = encrypt.HashPassword(txtFieldPass.Text);
        cust.profession = txtFieldJob.Text;
        cust.company = txtFieldCompany.Text;
        cust.subId = 1320;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string url = "https://www.example.com/api/customer/";
        var uri = new Uri(url);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cust);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);


        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
        {
            validationName.Text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            validationName.Text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

    }
```

And I am getting this error when I am executing the above function

> No HTTP  resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://www.example.com/api/customer/'.

But it is working fine in Postman with same variables.

I even verified the JSON generated in POSTMAN with the JSON being generated in the Visual Studio it is identical.

I am running this on iphone 8 iOS 12.0

Comment: What is the actual address that you are trying to reach? Is it localhost by any chance?

Comment: A quick google of the error message suggests that the error is generated from WebAPI so you are talking to your application, but the routing is wrong

Comment: No it is not a local host, i have hosted the API and the routing is not wrong, it is working in POSTMAN

Comment: Also check the TLS version, I'm not sure about Xamarin but in Dotnet Framework .NET 4.0 supports up to TLS 1.0 is the default TLS version. you can changes that in code.

Comment: I want to add that, with the same API my GET requests are working.

Comment: Xamarin uses TLS version 1.2

Comment: The url you are pointing to is actual website which doesn't have any `GET` defined on it. Its working on Postman probably because windows is routing it internally. Specify where exactly is your api and how example.com is routed to it

Comment: Also facing the same problem